# Disable trimming of bracket whitespace after a semicolon in vim

Tags: vsvim

I recently started working on source code which requires the following convention for function arguments:

```
void example( int arg );
```

However, after typing a semicolon, vim automatically trims any whitespace between the parenthesis:

```
void example(int arg); //after typing the ;
```

Is there a way to turn this feature off?

Comment: vim doesn't do that by default. Do you have any special plugins loaded?

Comment: I feel like an idiot. Yeah I was using the VsVim plugin in Visual Studio, and that formatting was being applied by Visual Studio, not VsVim.

Answer (score 1):

I was using VsVim and the trimming was being applied by Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

VisualStudio offers options to control such formatting behavior. Go to Tools > Options and search for "spacing".